# PHP having trouble grabbing data inbetween dates

Tags: php, date, if-statement

This is my weak spot...writing if statements to grab data inbetween two certain dates. I dont know what it is but it always confuses me.

```
if($date > $enddate || $date < $startdate){
```

the date is coming from the database and the startdate is 2013-05-06 and the enddate is 2013-06-05, I am trying to grab data inbetween those two dates.

Any help would be awesome thanks.

Comment: Assuming `$startdate` is before `$enddate`, your logic is reversed. You should check for dates _less than_ the end date AND _more than_ the start date.

Comment: it always helps, if you sort your "logical" conditions in the way you would "write" it. so "start < x < end" can be easily read as `($startdate < $date && $date < $enddate)` (Yes, you also wand AND `&&` not `||`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
if($date < $enddate && $date > $startdate){
```

If the dates come out of the database in the format "2013-05-06", you could also do something like this so you can actually compare properly:

```
//...get $date from the database...
$date = strtotime($date);
$startDate = strtotime("2013-05-06");
$endDate = strtotime("2013-06-05");
if($date < $enddate && $date > $startdate){
  //some code
}
```

The strtotime converts your date strings into UNIX timestamps which are numbers, making it easier to compare.

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ - you really shouldn't compare them that way - it will actually work when they're in Y-m-d format, though - the string ordering matches the date ordering.

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ It's perfectly fine to compare date strings in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the variables are dates, what user1578653 wrote is correct

```
if($date < $enddate && $date > $startdate){ }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

This is all assuming that they are dates, it would help if you showed us what kind of variables we are working with.

Answer (score 0):

Would `if (strtotime($date) > strtotime($start_date) && strtotime($date) < strtotime($end_date))` work?